# If $K$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=2$, prove that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for some square free integer $d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I think I have the later parts of this proof worked out pretty well but what's really stumping me is how to go from knowing $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=2$ to knowing that $K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$.

I mean all I know from $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=2$ is that every element of $K$ can be written in the form $bk_1 + ck_2$ for $b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$.  As far as I can tell I don't yet have any theorems at my disposal that say if $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite than $K$ must be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, or anything like that.  How do I go from this premise about $K$ as a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ to knowing something about elements of $K$ as roots of polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?  Thanks.

Comment: You know that a basis for a subspace ($\mathbb Q$ in this case) can be extended to a basis for $K$. A suitable basis for $\mathbb Q$ is $\{1\}$. Say you extend it by $\alpha$. Can you show that $\alpha$ must satisfy a quadratic equation? Can you massage $\alpha$ into a $\beta$ of the form you want?

Comment: If $K$ is $n$-dimensional, you get a relation between $1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^n$ by vector space stuff.

Comment: Use the quadratic formula, dude.

Comment: actually, this is true for any field $F$ s.t $char(F)\neq2$ (hint: consider what Zarrax wrote)

Comment: I'm vexed by Zarrax's and Dylan's comments, but going off of anthonyquas if I can show $\alpha^2$ is an element of the rationals than $\alpha$ is a solution to the equation $x^2 - \alpha^2$ which is in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  Is this the right direction?

Comment: @NollieTré The intent was not to vex! I was rushing off to do something else and completing the square is more or less the "trick", once you have a quadratic relation. [It need not be the case that the element of $K \setminus \mathbb Q$ you pick squares to something in $\mathbf Q$; you might pick $1 + \sqrt2$ inside of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$, for example] I didn't have time to go through the difficulties you list, and this I regret, since it seems that my comment may have been more confusing than helpful. In any event, I think Makoto's answer should clear things up.

Comment: @NollieTré I am confused about one thing. Do you know that an integer being square free is not the same as saying it is not a square in $\Bbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $\alpha \in K - \mathbb{Q}$.
Since $1 , α, α^2$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$, $aα^2 + bα + c = 0$, where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and not all of $a, b, c$ are zero.
By multiplying a suitable nonzero integer, we can assume $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$.
If $a = 0$, we get $bα + c = 0$.
Since $b$ or $c$ is not zero, this can't happen.
Hence $a \neq 0$.
Hence $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}((b^2 - 4ac)^{1/2})$.
Since 1$ , α$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, [$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}$] = 2. Hence $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and we are done.

Comment: Hello,can you explain please way 
$a \neq 0$ follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}((b^2 - 4ac)^{1/2})$ and why it means that 
[$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}$] = 2  ? thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This is easy enough once you know the primitive element theorem. Since any finite extension of  $\Bbb{Q}$ is separable it follows that $K = \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\notin \Bbb{Q}$ that has degree 2 over $\Bbb{Q}$. Suppose without loss of generality that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is

$$x^2 + bx + c.$$

Then by the quadratic formula, $\alpha = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4c}}{2}.$ Now $b^2 - 4c$ cannot be a square in $\Bbb{Q}$ for then this would contradict $\alpha$ not being a rational number. Furthermore because $b$ is a  rational number we have

$$\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)= \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{b^2 -4c})$$

so  finally at the end we can say that $K = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{e})$ where $e = b^2 - 4c$ that is not a square in $\Bbb{Q}$. Now write $e = \alpha/\beta$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are integers with $\alpha,\beta \neq 0$. We may assume that $e$ is in its lowest terms otherwise we can cancel factors off top and bottom. Then

$$\sqrt{e} = \sqrt{\alpha}/\sqrt{\beta} = \sqrt{\alpha\beta}/\beta$$

and consequently $K = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{e}) = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha\beta})$ because $\beta$ is an integer. Now if we write $d = \alpha\beta$, we have shown that $K = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, where $d$ is not the square of any integer.

$$\hspace{5in} \square$$

Comment: The full primitive element theorem is somewhat overkill here, since you are assuming that $[K:\mathbf{Q}]=2$. Any element $\alpha$ of $K\setminus\mathbf{Q}$ will be such that $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)=K$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell :D

Comment: You've got \mathbb Q(\sqrt{d}) for $d$ not a square in $\mathbb Q$, but you haven't quite shown it's a non-square *integer*... (upvoting anyway because it's really not a serious problem)

Comment: @BenMillwood Write $d = a/b$. Then $\sqrt{d} = \sqrt{a}/\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}/b$. And then $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{ab})$. Is this better?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure you've convinced me that your method of getting an integer preserves square-free-ness (it clearly doesn't if you don't choose $a$, $b$ coprime, for example) but possibly you can just say "if it turns out that $ab$ is not square-free, just take out any square factors". But this is really just pedantry and might be obscuring the real point of your argument, so I'm not picky :)

Comment: @BenMillwood I actually misread the question, and I don't think Makoto's answer addresses it too. The OP is looking for an integer $d$ such that $\Bbb{Z}/d\Bbb{Z}$ has trivial nilradical. I will try to correct that. By the way when we write $e = \alpha/\beta$, I have written above that we may assume the fraction is in its lowest terms.

Comment: @BenMillwood Feel free to edit my post, what matters at the end of the day is the quality of the answer, I feel it does not fully address the question; do edit it if you feel there is anything useful in completing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, we know that if $K/\Bbb Q$ is quadratic.  Then $K/\Bbb Q$ simple extension. Let $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha).$ Let $f$ be minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Then $K=\Bbb Q(D(f)).$