# An alternate proof for $[K:Q] = 2$ then $K = Q(\sqrt{d}), d$ square free

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

I've seen proofs of the above but I'd like to know if the following is also a valid proof:

So [K:Q] = 2 < $\infty$, so by the simple extension theorem:
$\exists \theta \in K$ such that K = $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$

> Claim 1: $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ = $\mathbb{Q}(\theta + q) $ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q} -\{0\}$

**Proof:**

a + b$\theta \in \mathbb{Q}(\theta) \Rightarrow a-bq+bq+b\theta = a-bq + b(q+\theta) \in \mathbb{Q}(\theta + q) \Rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\theta)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\theta + q)$

a+b($\theta+q) \in \mathbb{Q}(\theta + q) \Rightarrow a+bq + b\theta \in \mathbb{Q}(\theta) \Rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\theta+q)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$

So,
$\mathbb{Q}(\theta) = \mathbb{Q}(\theta + q)$

$\blacksquare$

> Claim 2: $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ = $\mathbb{Q}(q\theta) $ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q} -\{1\}$

**Proof**: similar to claim 1.

Then without a loss of generality: K = $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ with $\theta$ such that:
$\theta = q_1\phi + q_2$,   $\phi \in K, q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q} \iff q_1 = 1$ and $q_2 = 0$

Then since [K:Q] = 2, $\theta$ is the root of a minimal polynomial of degree two:
$P_{\theta}(x) = x^2 + \alpha x - \beta$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Q}$

Clearly $\beta \neq 0$, otherwise the polynomial is not irreducible.
Since $\theta$ is a root:
$\theta^2 + \alpha \theta - \beta = 0 \Rightarrow \theta = \dfrac{-\alpha}{2} \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 4\beta}}{2}$

But since this contradicts my assumption about theta not being written as a linear combination with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, $\alpha = 0$

so $P_\theta(x) = x^2 - \beta$, but this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $\sqrt{\beta}$ is not rational.

Moreover since $\sqrt{\beta} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\beta_1}{\beta_2}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{\beta_1\beta_2}}{\beta_2} $, $\beta_1, \beta_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$

But my claim about the form of $\theta$ requires that $\beta_2 = 1$ and my claim about the form of $\theta$ will mean that $\beta_1$ is square free (as otherwise there is a rational coefficient)

so $\theta = \sqrt{\beta_1}$

Is this proof fundamentally flawed by my assumption about the form of theta and if so why?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is flawed. We can't ensure a priori that $\phi$ is a 'pure square root'..

Comment: I fail to see how this is fundamentally different from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164721/if-k-is-an-extension-field-of-mathbbq-such-that-k-mathbbq-2-prove

Comment: @Berci
I'm confused as to exactly why specifying that theta takes that form in wrong? Don't $\theta = q_1 \phi + q_2 $ and $\phi$  both give rise to the same field extension?

Comment: Yes, that part is correct that $\Bbb Q(\theta) =\Bbb Q(\phi)$. Then you correctly find $\theta$ by the quadratic solution formula. But the implication $\alpha=0$ is not justified. That's true by the above, however, that $\Bbb Q(\theta) =\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta})$, and that can finish the proof. But the possibility to take $\alpha=0$ only follows after it.

Comment: @Berci Thank you!